# TEXT in Arabic showing wrong characters instead

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, special-characters, arabic

I've a Character Encoding issue.

I've a text file written in arabic, when i open it I get weird characters.. like this `åÇÜÇáÍÌÑäÇáÑÝÇÚíãäí`..

Is there any way to fix this and get a correct text? the text file where it is written is utf8x encoded.

Comment: That not in utf8 its in Windows-1256

Comment: how are you opening it- with what program?

Comment: I first got it encoded that way, then saved it to a file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment: it is not *UTF8*, it is *WINDOWS-1256* encoding, so you can repair it on Linux using `iconv` command for file `test`:

```
jh@jh-aspire:4804~$ iconv -fwindows-1256 -tutf8 test
هاـالحجرنالرفاعيمني
```

(I have no idea what it means as I don't know Arabic)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notepad++ for showing the Arabic texts.